# imagescreatetruecolor with a white background

Tags: php, image

I'm pretty sure I need to use imagefilledrectangle in order to get a white background instead of black on this... just not sure how. I've tried a few ways.

```
$targetImage = imagecreatetruecolor($thumbw,$thumbh);
imagecopyresized($targetImage,$sourceImage,0,0,0,0,$thumbWidth,$thumbHeight,imagesx($sourceImage),imagesy($sourceImage));
```

Comment: To anyone as clueless as me. imagefill was the answer:

    `$targetImage = imagecreatetruecolor($thumbw,$thumbh);
$white = imagecolorallocate($targetImage, 255, 255, 255);
imagefill($targetImage, 0, 0, $white);
imagecopyresized($targetImage,$sourceImage,0,0,0,0,$thumbWidth,$thumbHeight,imagesx($sourceImage),imagesy($sourceImage));`

Answer (score 45):

**UPDATE (2020):** Please see this answer below for a faster fill than imagefill: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32580839/1005039

**ORIGINAL**

From the [PHP manual entry for imagefill](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagefill.php):

```
$image = imagecreatetruecolor(100, 100);

// set background to white
$white = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
imagefill($image, 0, 0, $white);
```

Comment: Hi @user3473227 - Your edit was actually correct. I've updated my answer to reflect your change. (Sorry it got rejected.)

Answer (score 15):

imagefill() uses flood fill, which is quite slow compared to just painting a color in a rectangle without regard for the content of the image. So imagefilledrectangle() will be a lot quicker.

```
// get size of target image
$width  = imagesx($targetImage);
$height = imagesy($targetImage);

// get the color white
$white  = imagecolorallocate($targetImage,255,255,255);

// fill entire image (quickly)
imagefilledrectangle($targetImage,0,0,$width-1,$height-1,$white);
```

Speed is often a consideration when writing code.

Comment: with imagefill a I have a problem "memory exausted", imagefilledrectangle solve. tks

Comment: This should be accepted as correct answer. "imagefill()" is really slow compared to this solution and it can cause issues on servers with low memory limit.

Comment: The initial part of the code sets up a white background, but it doesn't handle the placement of the resized source image onto that background

Answer (score 3):

```
$targetImage = imagecreatetruecolor($thumbw,$thumbh);

// get the color white
$color = imagecolorallocate($targetImage, 255, 255, 255);

// fill entire image
imagefill($targetImage, 0, 0, $color);
```

imagecolorallocate: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorallocate.php

imagefill: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefill.php