# PHP GD multiple images with white background - warnings?

Tags: php, image-processing, warnings, gd

I use php imagecolorallocate() and imagefill() in an image upload to also let png files have a white background  (like in this post: [imagescreatetruecolor with a white background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135271/imagescreatetruecolor-with-a-white-background))

Here is the part of the code it concerns:

```
    //create new images
    $nimgac_0=imagecreatetruecolor($maxw_img0,$maxh_img0); //img1
    $nimgac_1=imagecreatetruecolor($maxw_img1,$maxh_img1); //img2
    $nimgac_2=imagecreatetruecolor($maxw_img2,$maxh_img2); //img3

    $nimgaa_0=imagecolorallocate($nimgac_0,255,255,255);
    $nimgaa_1=imagecolorallocate($nimgac_1,255,255,255);
    $nimgaa_2=imagecolorallocate($nimgac_2,255,255,255);

    $nimga_0=imagefill($nimgac_0,0,0,$nimgaa_0);
    $nimga_1=imagefill($nimgac_1,0,0,$nimgaa_1);
    $nimga_2=imagefill($nimgac_2,0,0,$nimgaa_2);

    //create images from temp folder
        if ($type=="jpg") {
            $nimgb_0=imagecreatefromjpeg("../imga/".$_FILES['file']['name']);
            $nimgb_1=imagecreatefromjpeg("../imga/".$_FILES['file']['name']);
            $nimgb_2=imagecreatefromjpeg("../imga/".$_FILES['file']['name']);
        }

        if ($type=="png") {
            $nimgb_0=imagecreatefrompng("../imga/".$_FILES['file']['name']);
            $nimgb_1=imagecreatefrompng("../imga/".$_FILES['file']['name']);
            $nimgb_2=imagecreatefrompng("../imga/".$_FILES['file']['name']);
        }


    imagecopyresized($nimga_0,$nimgb_0,0,0,0,0,$nwidth_0,$nheight_0,$width,$height);
    imagecopyresized($nimga_1,$nimgb_1,0,0,0,0,$nwidth_1,$nheight_1,$width,$height);
    imagecopyresized($nimga_2,$nimgb_2,0,0,0,0,$nwidth_2,$nheight_2,$width,$height);

    imagejpeg($nimga_0,"../imga/".$_FILES['file']['name'],80);
    imagejpeg($nimga_1,"../imga/".$imgname_1,80);
    imagejpeg($nimga_2,"../imga/".$imgname_2,80);
```

but I get this warnings:

> Warning: imagecopyresized() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   boolean given in ... on line 114
>
> Warning: imagecopyresized() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   boolean given in ... on line 115
>
> Warning: imagecopyresized() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   boolean given in ... on line 116
>
> Warning: imagejpeg() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
>   in ... on line 117
>
> Warning: imagejpeg() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
>   in ... on line 118
>
> Warning: imagejpeg() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
>   in ... on line 119
>
> Warning: imagedestroy() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean
>   given in ... on line 120
>
> Warning: imagedestroy() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean
>   given ... on line 121
>
> Warning: imagedestroy() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean
>   given in ... on line 122

Same code without the immagecolorallocate() and imagefill() works perfectly fine. However, I cannot find any error or any difference to the above posted code.

Anyone any ideas? Thank you in advance!

PS: I want to save all images as jpg, that's why I convert pngs to jpg too.

EDIT 3 (sorry, I got confused):

`print_r(getimagesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']));` returns

> Array ( [0] => 354 [1] => 332 [2] => 2 [3] => width="354" height="332" [bits] => 8 [channels] => 3 [mime] => image/jpeg )

so, everything is fine with `if($size['2']==3) {$type="jpg";}`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found the answer to my problem and thought I should post it here step by step so if someone should have the same problem one day, here is what I figured out:

Basically, I had `$nimga_0=imagefill($nimgac_0,0,0,$nimgaa_0);` in my code, whereas imagefill is a bool. So, imagefill was successful and I assigned its value 1 to $nimga_0, and then wanted to use 1 as a resource in `imagecopyresized($nimga_0,$nimgb_0,0,0,0,0,$nwidth_0,$nheight_0,$width,$height);`.

Of course, this cannot be a valid source. All I had to change was leaving out the vars and just do:

```
imagefill($nimgac_0,0,0,$nimgaa_0);
```

---

**STEP BY STEP**

I created a canvas with

```
$nimgac_0=imagecreatetruecolor($maxw_img0,$maxh_img0);
```

then the white color with

```
$nimgaa_0=imagecolorallocate($nimgac_0,255,255,255);
```

and then just had to fill the canvas with the color using

```
imagefill($nimgac_0,0,0,$nimgaa_0);
```

Then I copy the uploaded image with

```
$nimgb_0=imagecreatefromjpeg("../imga/".$_FILES['file']['name']);
```

then copy the uploaded image onto the (now white colored) canvas

```
imagecopyresized($nimgac_0,$nimgb_0,0,0,0,0,$nwidth_0,$nheight_0,$width,$height);
```

and save as jpg

```
imagejpeg($nimgac_0,"../imga/".$_FILES['file']['name'],80);
```

and finally clear the cache

```
imagedestroy($nimgac_0);
```

Hope it helps someone else too :)

Answer (score 1):

"Boolean given" usually means that an operation failed, and instead of returning a GD handle, returned a boolean false. You then use this false value elsewhere in another GD call, and get that warning.

So look at whatever your line 114 is in that code, figure out where the GD handle you're using there came from, and then figure out why the operation that should've generated that handle produced a false value instead.

---

ok, with what's come out of the comments below, here's your problem:

```
$size = getimagesize($_FILES[ blah blah blah]);
```

returns an array. You then compare this array against an int:

```
$size == 2
```

which will fail. So $type comes out to be blank. That means NONE of the imagecreatefromXXX() functions are called, and your $nimgb_XXX image handles never get defined.

However, you pass those undefined handle variables into the various other GD functions, and then you get your warning. Somehow the auto-created `null` values that PHP puts into those variables is being reported as a FALSE by the GD library.

Your code should be this:

```
$info = getimagesize(...);
switch($info['type']) {
    case IMGTYPE_JPG:
         $nimgb_0=imagecreatefromjpeg("../imga/".$_FILES['file']['name']);
         $nimgb_1=imagecreatefromjpeg("../imga/".$_FILES['file']['name']);
         $nimgb_2=imagecreatefromjpeg("../imga/".$_FILES['file']['name']);
         break;
    case IMGTYPE_PNG:
         etc....
    default:
         die("Unsupported file type");
}
```

The IMGTYPE_... constants are documented here: http://php.net/manual/en/image.constants.php

Comment: Thank you Marc, it is the lines with imagecopyresized(). As the warning does not occur if I do not use image allocate and imagefill, I thought it must be because of them?

Comment: That's where the warning occurs, but the actual problem occured earlier, when a previous GD call failed and returned a false value. You'll have to figur eout which one of the copyresized arguments is causing it (src img, dst img, etc...), then figure out why it got a false value earlier on.

Comment: yes, I think like said it must be because of imagecolorallocate() and imagefill() as the same code without those two calls works perfectly fine... so, I referred to the other question in stack overflow. I thought my code is exactly like there, but probably I have some error... how can I find out what causes them to fail?

Comment: Check that the file uploads actually succeeded - you're reading directly from the tmp file that PHP creates for the upload. If the upload fails, those files won't exist and you'll get FALSE for the results of imagecreatefromjpeg/png

Comment: the file upload works, i actually show the file right after in the body... and I use move_uploaded_file, of course

Comment: where is $type defined? is that from $_FILES['file']['type']? If so, then you need to compare mime types: image/jpeg, image/png, not 'jpg' or 'png.

Comment: it is from $size=getimagesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']); if ($size==2) {$type="jpg";} not the best code or shortest, probably...

Comment: getimagesize returns an array. You'd need $size[2] to get the image type code. http://php.net/getimagesize

Comment: yes, sorry.. I have that... i copied it wrong here. Thank you, I appreciate your effort. However, pls note that the whole process works fine except when adding the imagecolorallocate and imagefill. In addition, none of the steps returns false...

Comment: No, sorry Marc. That is not what it fails at. NOTE PLS that it the upload works fine, just the background color is the problem.