# PHP Issue with using imagefill() for a white background after imagecreatetruecolor()

Tags: php, image-processing

I have a gallery tool in which all of my images have to fit into a 515px X 343px space while being centered.  I have the proportions preserved and successfully center the image in that space with a black background on either side (top,right,bottom,left) Which ever are left open after the resize.  Images may be taller or wider then the given specs.

I need to make that black background white and tried following the answers suggested at this question [imagescreatetruecolor with a white background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135271/imagescreatetruecolor-with-a-white-background)  On an image which is taller I successfully turn the left side white but I can't get the right side of the image to be white.  Here is the portion of my code.

```
$file1new = imagecreatetruecolor($framewidth, $frameheight);

if(isset($fromMidX) && $fromMidX > 0){
    $white = imagecolorallocate($file1new, 255, 255, 255); 
    $rightOffset = ($framewidth - $fromMidX) + 1;
    imagefill($file1new, 0, 0, $white);  //Line 1
    imagefill($file1new, $rightOffset, 0, $white); //Line 2 
}
```

The variables $framewidth = 515, $framheight = 343, $fromMidX is the x-coordinate offset.  If I replace $rightOffset with a static amount of 510 on Line 2 the right side is still all black (even the last 5 px).  Better yet, is I comment out line 1 but not line 2, the left side remains white and the right side remains black.

The way I understand how imagefill() works is that it starts from the given X,Y coordinates and floods what ever color is at that pixel with the new color, which in my case would be 255,255,255.  So I figured the reason I was getting the white only on the one side is because my image was splitting the canvas in two.  That is why I added the second imagefill() for the right side.

The only thing that gets me is that I am using the imagefill()'s before I even bring the object of my uploaded image into the equation.  So I don't know how that could be effecting what gets filled with white.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT 1:
After the code above I have this:

```
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($image); //Line 3
imagecopyresampled($file1new, $source , $fromMidX, $fromMidY , 0, 0, $framewidth, /$frameheight, $w, $h); //Line 4
imagejpeg($file1new, $image,85);
imagedestroy($file1new);
```

The variable $image is the location of my uploaded image after

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $location);
$image = $location;
```

If I comment out Line 3 and Line 4 then the resulting image is all white.

I also believed that I am flooding the image with all white before applying any resizing operations on my image.

Comment: Do you have a completely white image if you leave out the other image altogether? `imagefill($file1new, 0, 0, $white);` should be totally sufficient. Remove the `if`.

Comment: Try this: create a completely white image, which will serve as the background, than just merge it with your irregular picture. Consider this function http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php it will make sence to you

Comment: Far easier to simply floodfill the new image with white before you do any of those thumbnail operations on it.

Comment: Isn't that what he did? "I am using the imagefill()'s before I even bring the object of my uploaded image into the equation. So I don't know how that could be effecting what gets filled with white."

Comment: I am looking into imagecopymerge() right now Pablo.  I will post if it works or not for what I am doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try refilling the right side after loading the requested image?

```
<?php
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($image); //Line 3
$file1new = imagecreatetruecolor($framewidth, $frameheight);

$white = imagecolorallocate($file1new, 255, 255, 255);
//fill whole image with white color
imagefill($file1new, 0, 0, $white);  //Line 1

//find right side of image
$rightOffset = ($framewidth - $fromMidX) + 1;

//insert source file into new image
imagecopyresampled($file1new, $source , $fromMidX, $fromMidY , 0, 0, $framewidth, $frameheight, $w, $h); //Line 4

//fill image right hand side with white
imagefill($file1new, $rightOffset, 0, $white); //Line 2 

imagejpeg($file1new, $image,85);
imagedestroy($file1new);
?>
```

Comment: VortexTangent, that did it.  It also required the least amount of changes to what I had.  I'm sure the use of imagecopymerge() would have worked also.  Thank you.

Comment: Cool, it's odd that it would fill the right hand side with black after image is placed... maybe `$framewidth` is too large and image gets filled with black instead of resizing/stretching because of some option?  I'm not too familiar with GD library.